# When assigning a pointer to the memory address of an array, why don't you have to use the address operator?

Tags: c++, pointers

When you want a pointer to point to memory address of a variable you use the address operator(&) but when you want a pointer to point to an array you just use the array name without the address operator, why is this?

Comment: You *can* use `&` just fine, it's just that [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/364696) means if you don't, the array still implicitly decays to a pointer.

Comment: Because it is one of the weird things that you just have to get used to about c++ (and c)

Comment: You can use either `array` or `&array[0]`, the address of the first element.

Comment: Because the syntax rules of C++ (and C) specify that using the name of an array in a context where a pointer is expected, gives a pointer to its first element.   Using `&array` gives something else (address of the array, not the address of the first element).

Comment: @Peter Array decay does not depend on names. Any explanation involving "the name of an array" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The premise is incorrect. If you don't use `&`, you don't get a pointer to the array; you get a pointer to the first element of the array.

That is:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int *p1 = arr;
int *p2 = &arr[0];

int (*p3)[4] = &arr;
```

`p1` and `p2` are equivalent. They both point to the first element of the array, `arr[0]`.

`p3` is a pointer to the whole array, and it does need `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are implemented as contiguous memory location in the memory. When you write something like

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *p = arr
```

Then here `arr` is just a pointer of base type `int` pointing to the first element in the array and the `[]` operator is just helping in its incrementation

e.g.

```
arr[2]; // same as *(arr+2)
p[2]; // same as *(p+2) i.e. arr[2]
```

As @melpomene mentioned your question is not wholly correct. A pointer to an array implies something like

```
int (*p)[3] = &arr;
```

Here the pointer has a base type of `int [3]`, so when you increment (`p++`), then p would increment by 3 `int`.

Pointers to arrays are more visible in case of multi dimensional arrays